# Resharper: 'contains' mode searching

Tags: resharper

Is it a way to set up Resharper to **search inside names** (instead from beginning) ?
Eg assume when pressing Alt + \ in dialog's results I can see

- JohnSmith
- JonnyBalboa
- MariaSmith

I'm looking for all members contain '**Smith**' substring - so I'm forced to use asterisk:
***Smith**

But I want just enter 'Smith' without anything more (like in DPack)

**EDIT**
I've opened R# ticket for this. If anyone interested **[PLEASE VOTE !](http://www.jetbrains.net/jira/browse/RSRP-121257)**

**UPDATE**

'Contains' mode was implemented in R# ver 5. Works perfectly. Even better I dreamed - intellisence also supports that! 
Try it and vote for it!

(RS v5. available [here](http://www.jetbrains.net/confluence/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+5.0+Nightly+Builds))

Comment: I opened a similar ticket relating to 'contains' searching and filtering in intellisense popups: http://www.jetbrains.net/jira/browse/RSRP-101619

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is available.  You would always have to enter a '*' at the beginning.

If you feel that this is a feature you would use (personally I think I'd find it annoying as I usually search for items by prefix) then you can enter a suggestion on their issue tracking site:

http://www.jetbrains.net/jira/browse/RSRP

Not directly related to your question, but one way of searching for an exact match (i.e. not a prefix) is to include a space after your search term.

Comment: I don't really think this is annoying - eg if you have implemented event "Form_Load" you can just enter "Load" to navigate - "Form" is v.common.
Of course we can always try rename VS auto generated events to be more uniq. / fit to R# searching method etc
But I think R# shall be more flexible in that matter and give config option allowing user searching as he like :)

Anyway thanks for URL - I'll definitely put there my suggestion.

Comment: I work on quite large solution files with many 3rd party and in-house APIs loaded.  Searching by prefix already often turns up more results than I'd like, so having a 'contains' versus a 'startswith' search would return even more.  I also don't see how you could do a one-off startswith search if your suggestion was implemented.  Let us know what JetBrains say about your suggestion!

Comment: Drew, we are already experimenting with 'contains' mode, and we don't like how it works now, but we have some ideas about how to make it much better. Let's wait for 5.0 :)

Comment: Ilya, based on some of the long-term issues I'm seeing closed against version 5, I'm looking forward to seeing what's in the release.

Comment: @Ilya - I dont know wy you dont like how contains work. Do you like how actually *search_pattern work? I do :) So please add additional option in R# cfg not forcing on me putting asterisk each time I start searching :)

Comment: @Maciej, adding an option is the last thing we would like to do. There are already lots of options in ReSharper. I'd like to cut half of them, actually :)